# IBM ODM: HTDS and SOAP Fault Response

Tags: java, soap, rules, fault, ibm-odm

I made a really simple RuleApp with IBM ODM and deployed it to Rule Execution Server (RES).

I intend to invoke this app with the SOAP protocol, so I retrieved the WSDL definition from HTDS.

Input to this service is a simple class with one string field named `input1`.

Output class is simple too, with one string field - `output1`.

When I invoke this SOAP service with the `input1` value of "Error", I want to respond with SOAP Fault and customize it's Description field.

Otherwise, I want to send a regular response with the `output1` field set to "success!".

I tried doing this with Action Rule and an `if` `else` statement, throwing new java.lang.Exception.

In case of `input1=="Error"`, the exception is Invoked, and I get a SOAP Fault message with stack trace printed in Description field.

I am interested in how to customize this Fault response, so I can set the description field to "something" and faultactor field to "something2" and faultstring to "something3"?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anyone do what you are attempting to do.

Generally speaking, I would not expect the SOAP Fault to be used to report back business-level information. I would expect business results, even negative or exceptional results, to be reported back in the SOAP Response, leaving the SOAP Fault to deal with server-level issues.

I would encourage you to do as little customization as possible, making do with out-of-the-box functionality if at all feasible. The whole point of running ODM via HTDS is to standardize everything to avoid having to deal with inter-process communications issues, leaving more time to focus on solving the business-level problem instead.